# When registering an instance in aws load balancer, it says inservice, but it does not run

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I registered an instance with the load balancer, and index.html of the public DNS address of the instance is accessed.
However, the instance appears as an inservice on the load balancer, but it says N / A, and the index.html of the DNS address of the load balancer does not run.
After hearing that it took time to register, I tried again two days later, but it still doesn't work.
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Is it ALB, NLB or CLB? Does the instance work by itself? Without LB, the website is accessible?

Comment: The load balancer is a classic load balancer and the instance works itself. Without a load balancer, I can connect to the instance's DNS and not to the load balancer's DNS.
(I'm sorry for the lack of communication because I don't speak English well.)

Comment: A possibility can be failure of health checks as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-register-instance.html#ts-elb-register-too-long). Have you checked them?

Comment: Thank you very much!! As I slowly walked through the documents you gave me, and checked them one by one, I found that the security group settings for the instance and the load balancer were different. It was a problem that I had been thinking about for more than 2 days, but I solved it. Thank you again very much!!

Comment: Cool. I will make answer for future reference then.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments.

The issue turned out to be incorrectly set **security groups**.

Other common possible reasons are listed in the aws documentation:

> [Troubleshoot a Classic Load Balancer: Instance Registration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-register-instance.html)